# Creating a new matrix under specified condition from user inputted matrix

Tags: python, matrix

As a newbie to python, I've come across a task that I'm having trouble completing. I am supposed to create a new matrix, taking into consideration the original one, inputted by the user, where each element corresponds to the number of adjacent elements greater or equal to the corresponding one in the original matrix. Since English is not my native language, I might not have presented it properly so here is an example:

```
input:
3x3 matrix
9 14 13
3 0  7
8 15 15

output:
3x3 matrix
2 5 2
1 0 1 
2 5 3
```

So, if it isn't clear, the new matrix determines how many adjacent elements are greater or equal to an element in the original one. 9 is greater than 3 & 0, so that results in "2", 14 is greater than all the adjacent ones so it prints out "5", etc... It also takes diagonals into consideration, of course.

So far, I've got down the input of the original matrix but I'm unsure how to proceed further. I am not someone who's got access to university materials, professors or peer help and my experimentation and search online has been futile so far. I do not need a complete solution, rather than pointers and concept explanation.

This is the code so far:

```
# matrix input
  
rOne = int(input("Number of rows:")) 
cOne = int(input("Number of columns:")) 
  
# initialize matrix 
matrixOne = [] 
print("Enter elements rowwise:") 
  
# user input
for i in range(rOne):          # for loop za redove
    a =[] 
    for j in range(cOne):      # for loop za kolone 
         a.append(int(input())) 
    matrixOne.append(a) 
  
  

# print matrix one
for i in range(rOne): 
    for j in range(cOne): 
        print(matrixOne[i][j], end = " ") 
    print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually managed to solve the thing, feels amazing :D

```
def get_neighbor_elements(current_row, current_col, total_rows, total_cols):
    neighbors = []
    for i in [-1, 0, 1]:  # red pre, isti red, red posle
        for j in [-1, 0, 1]:  # kolona pre, ista kolona, kolona posle
            row = current_row + i
            col = current_col + j
            if row < 0 or col < 0 or row >= total_rows or col >= total_cols:  # preskace se ako se izaslo iz granica matrice
                continue
            if row == current_row and col == current_col:# ako su red i kolona isti, preskace se(to je taj isti element)
                continue
            neighbor = [row, col]
            neighbors.append(neighbor)
    return neighbors
 
 
def make_new_matrix(old_matrix):
    new_matrix = []
    for i in range(len(old_matrix)):
        new_matrix.append([])
    for i in range(len(old_matrix)):  # iteriramo kroz redove stare matrice
        for j in range(len(old_matrix[i])):  # iteriramo kroz kolone stare matrice
            neighbors = get_neighbor_elements(i, j, len(old_matrix), len(old_matrix[i]))  # dobavljamo komsije
            count = 0
            for neighbor in neighbors:  # sad gledamo da li je trenutni element veci ili jednak susednim
                if old_matrix[i][j] >= old_matrix[neighbor[0]][neighbor[1]]:
                    count += 1
            new_matrix[i].append(count)
    return new_matrix
 
 
def print_matrix(matrix):
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            print(str(matrix[i][j]) + "   ", end='')
        print()
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    matrix = [[12, 10], [2, 10]]
    print("Old matrix: ")
    print_matrix(matrix)
    new_matrix = make_new_matrix(matrix)
    print("New matrix")
    print_matrix(new_matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that can do the exact thing:

```
def adj_matrix(matrixOne, rOne, cOne):
    
    new_lst = []
    
    for i in range(rOne):
        a = []
        for j in range(cOne):
            count = 0
            x, y = (i, j) # matrix values here
            cells = list(starmap(lambda a,b: (x+a, y+b), product((0,-1,+1), (0,-1,+1)))) # this will find all the adjacent index
    
            filtered_cell = [p for p in cells if (sum(p)>=0 and prod(p)>=0)] # this filters out all the negative indexs
            filtered_cell = [p for p in filtered_cell if p[0]<rOne and p[1]<cOne] # this filters out index that are greater than matrix
    
            for z in filtered_cell:
                if matrixOne[i][j] >= matrixOne[z[0]][z[1]]:
                    count += 1
            
            a.append(count-1)
        new_lst.append(a)

    return new_lst
```

also import:

```
from itertools import product, starmap

from math import prod
```